# Run same function 5 min later firebase cloud functions NOT Cron

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've searched the internet but haven't found anything that works for me.
I describe what I need.

- I have a function in firebase that is executed every time I add a new node to my Realtime Database

  ```
  exports.makeMagic = functions.database.ref("/users/{uid}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const iterate = snap.val();
    if(iterate1.loops <= 5){
        // run 5 minutes later
        myFunction(iterate1,iterate2,iterate3); 
    }
  });
  ```

What I need is for `myFunction` to make a change to the database. But it must be strictly 5 minutes after the node is created. Not before and not after. I also don't want a cron job that is always running checking.

I have also read about using `settimeout`
But this would block my "`makeMagic`" function, until the 5 minutes were up. And I think maximum can last 1 minute, I'm not sure about that.

Any help would be nice to keep trying

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/), as explained in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).

You will need to write another Cloud Function, of type HTTPS, which implements the desired business logic.